# Removing duplicates from intersection list in Scheme

Tags: list, duplicates, scheme, racket, intersection

I have a piece of code that can get the intersection of two lists. However i want to remove all the duplicates from the list. I use the function`remove-duplicates()`. Whenever I use it, drRacket gives the following error.

> application: not a procedure;
>    expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
>     given: (a b c c d)
>     arguments...: [none]

Here is my code

```
#lang scheme
(define (intersect lst1 lst2)
  (removedup(lst1 lst2))
    (cond
      ((null? lst1)(quote ()))
      ((isin? (car lst1) lst2)
       (cons (car lst1)
             (intersect (cdr lst1) lst2)))
      (else (intersect (cdr lst1) lst2))))

(define (removedup lst1 lst2)
  (remove-duplicates(lst1))
  (remove-duplicates(lst2))
  )

(define (isin? a lat)
    (cond
      ((null? lat) #f)
      (else (or (equal? (car lat) a)
                (isin? a (cdr lat))))))
```

My input is `> (intersect '(a b c c d) '(c d e f))`

Can anyone help me solve my problem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're coming to Racket from another language. In Racket and Scheme, you can't add extra parentheses; each pair of parentheses has a specific meaning. In this case, you have written

```
(remove-duplicates(lst1))
```

when you meant to write

```
(remove-duplicates lst1)
```

The first of these has two function calls: a call to lst1, and then a call to remove-duplicates with the result. The first of these can't succeed, because lst1 isn't a function.

Also, take a look at the pink highlighting that DrRacket gives you; it's probably highlighting the problem area.

Also note that when you fix this bug you may get another very similar one ... on the next line?

Comment: Thanks! Managed to remove the errors. However I still do not get the result I want.  My input is > (intersect '(a b c c d) '(c d e f)). And my output is, (c c d). I want my output to be (c d).

Comment: @LvanRooij Racket is a functional programming language, and most functions are pure when possible. `remove-duplicates` does not modify its arguments (in fact, lists are immutable in Racket), it simply returns a new list with the duplicates removed. You should wrap your return value with `remove-duplicates`, not attempt to call it for a side-effect.

Comment: Test cases are key, here. Also, if you're not sure how functions get evaluated, try using the stepper to build your intuition. Becoming a programmer requires formulating hypotheses about what's going on, and testing them.